# How to set default value for a managed field in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a managed field from a package. The requirement is such that I can not add this field to page layout. But when I create or clone a record some managed code throws the error that the particular field is required. Since it is not included in page layout, users can not set any value.

Is there any way I can set a default value for this field?

Comment: What do you mean with "manage field" ? custom field on managed package? or package attribute? I suppose you already know `Default Values` (https://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/custom_field_attributes.htm#DefaultValue)

Comment: I am talking about field from a managed package

Comment: I used to solve default values issues using a `input type=hidden`, couldn't you?

Comment: Martin, can u please explain your comment. Thanks

Comment: Adding an inputHidden to your page layout you could set any default value for a specific required field. e.g: `<apex:inputHidden id="hiddenField" value="{!CustomObj_c.field__c}"/>` .... and then using js you can set a value : `document.getElementById('hiddenField').value = 'your default value'` ..... I really don't know if I understood your question :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a default value the easy way like you would with one of your custom fields. First I would try it with a simple Workflow Rule / Field Update combo. For the Workflow Rule you could use a formula condition like ISBLANK(PKG_*Field*_c). Choose your default in the Field Update. I'm a little worried that the error will be raised before your workflow has a chance to populate it. If so, you could resort to a Before Insert trigger.

Comment: You are correct, the error is raised before workflows are kicked off and even ahead of before insert triggers. So, both workflows and before insert triggers are not an option in this case. Please advise.

Comment: Bummer. Both approaches have worked for me to default managed fields, but they weren't required. I'm down to wild guesses at this point. One guess is to create the record through code and then show them an edit screen instead of trying to handle this on a new record screen. I think Martin's comments might work if you're building a custom visual force page for this--something like a quick create screen. Hopefully we get some other answers, I'm curious too. Voting up your question.